# PHP MYSQL link array with uuid Json

Tags: php, mysql, json

First of all, I'm happy to see people helping people here :D.

I got also a small issue sadly,

DB 1 contains:
UUID and much values.

DB 2 contains: 
UUID and again many other values.

what I want is

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [UUID] => 96
            [DB1 values]
            [DB2 values] 
        )
```

i thought that will work with array_combine but that isn't true sadly because then i miss some db1 values

[here database images:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPfN3.png)

Comment: Can you show some table-structure? Sounds like you want to `JOIN` those two tables (or do you mean they are different *databases?*).

Comment: Please provide more info. How do the arrays you want to combine look like?

Comment: I added a picture @Qirel

Comment: @JorisDijkstra Yes, but is that different tables - or different databases? (Sounds like you mean tables, but you wrote databases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--EDIT--
Your picture helped. You can handle that at the SQL Level

```
SELECT Login.*, Location.*
FROM Login
LEFT JOIN Location ON Login.UUID=Location.UUID
GROUP BY Login.UUID
```

Then the resulting data in PHP will already be correctly formatted.
Notice that I chose table `Login` to drive the query, could have also chosen the `Location` table. depends on the underlying structure

Comment: it's almost my idea but i got a small issue on this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [PName] => test [UUID] => 42bf8ad8-bbad-4afc-a104-786851b61cc0 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [UUID] => 42bf8ad8-bbad-4afc-a104-786851b61cc0 [Lat] => -10 [Long] => 100 [Speed] => 100 [Datetime] => 2017-08-25 18:12:54 ) ) ` 

he creates [0] and [1] UUID area equal

Comment: Added picture for structure logic :D